# react-navigation's weird behavior when back button is pressed on the second tab. (React Native)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm making app with using React Native. 
I have a tabNavigator.

If I go to second tab and press back button on the top navigation bar, It goes to first tab instead go back to previous screen.

I also noticed this behavior on sample app of react-navigation as well, so maybe it's made like that way.

Can't I make my tab navigator go previous screen regardless which tab I press the back button from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed the default behavior of react-navigation.

You can change it in the definition of your tab navigator, by specifying

```
backBehavior: 'none'
```

See [the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-navigator.html) for more.

Example:

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Tab1: {screen: Screen1},
  Tab2: {screen: Screen2},
  Tab3: {screen: Screen3}
}, {
  backBehavior: 'none'
});
```

Comment: Nimrod! Thanks so much!

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: I would have done that, but there was time requirement! I did now!